# Why 0xFEFF appear in recv data

Tags: python, c++, flask, winapi

i try to create a client written in c++ and a server using python flask. The task is simple, client connect and get data from server, then display it on console. I have two piece of code:

Server:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "hello".encode("utf-16")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host="127.0.0.1")
```

Client:

```
BOOL bResults = FALSE;
    bool ret = false;
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
    WCHAR wDataRecv[1024] = {0};
    HINTERNET hConnect = NULL;
    HINTERNET hRequest = NULL;
    DWORD dwSize = 0;

    HINTERNET hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0); # open session to connect
    hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, L"localhost", (port == 0) ? INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT : port, 0); # connect to localhost with port 80 or custom port (this time i use port 5000)
    if (!hConnect)
        goto Free_And_Exit;
    hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", L"/hello", NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 0); 
    
    if (hRequest) {
        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, NULL, 0,WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0,0, 0);# send GET request
    }

    if (bResults)
        bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);

    if (bResults)
    {
        dwSize = 0;
        if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize)) {
            std::cout << "WinHttpQueryDataAvailable failed with code: " << GetLastError();
        }
        if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, wDataRecv, dwSize, &dwDownloaded)) {
            std::cout << "WinHttpReadData failed with code: " << GetLastError();
        }
        std::wcout << wDataRecv; # wcout wont print anything to console
    }
Free_And_Exit: #clean up
    if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    return ret;
```

I noticed that the data return from server like:

> b'\xfe\xff\hello'

Why 0xFEFF is there ?

Comment: I smell a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: ... put there, presumably, by the `encode("utf-16")` function.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes i can confirmed that. Thanks

Comment: All calls to `GetLastError` happen too late and may no longer provide useful information. You will have to call `GetLastError` *immediately* after entering a state where the respective API call is documented to return a meaningful value, **without any intervening code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its is BOM (byte order mark). I just need to decode from the client or use:

```
return "hello".encode('UTF-16LE') # not UTF-16
```

Comment: Note: You're encoding is UTF-16. That means endianness comes into play. By reading the BOM you will know whether the receiver and sender are on the same endianness or octets need to be flipped. The leading 16-bit value will be either 0xFEFF or 0xFFEF. The former indicates you're good; the latter indicates a pre-filter to swap octets is required. A reasonable "converter" will do it for you.

Comment: A more conventional way to go about this is to use UTF-8 instead. It's the de-facto standard encoding for any text in information interchange scenarios, especially when crossing machine boundaries. You'll still have to (potentially) account for a BOM, but there will no longer be a need to swap bytes around, as UTF-8 is endianness-agnostic.

Comment: @IInspectable I've never seen any Interchange protocol use the UTF-8 BOM. Besides, the Unicode consortium discourages use of the UTF-8 BOM in general anyway.

Comment: @rem Web servers will frequently prepend a BOM to content they serve. Whether that conforms to any given protocol doesn't change the fact that it is happening. Incidentally, that's what the web server in the question would do if `"utf-16"` were to be replaced by `"utf-8"`.

Comment: @IInspectable web servers don't need to use a BOM, they have the Content-Type header to declare the encordng.

Comment: @rem I'm perfectly aware of that. I'm also aware that HTML documents can [specify their encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset), again. None of that changes the fact that implementations don't necessarily follow best practices or even protocols. Case in point being the OP's code that's apparently planning to send a BOM from their `GET` request handler.